# Sql While loop doesn't increment variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I am currently trying to fill a table (BIV) with some values. What I want to achieve is the following content:

```
ID    OldState    NewState
 0           0           0
 1           0           0
 2           0           0 
 3           0           0
 ...
511          0           0
```

I want to fill rows manually one single time with values from 0 ... 511.

I thought that would be an easy thing to do:

```
DELETE FROM BIV

DECLARE @id as int
SET @id = 0;

WHILE @id < 512
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BIV (Id, OldState, NewState) VALUES (@id, 0 ,0);
    SET @id = @id + 1;
END;
```

Yet, I end up with the following

```
ID    OldState    NewState
 0           0           0
 1           0           0
 1           0           0 
 1           0           0
...          0           0
 1           0           0
(512 rows in total)
```

It seems to me that @id is not incremented the way I want it to (but it is incremented once). This looks like the value of @id is not retained between the iterations.

So, what am I missing? I don't mind performance, this is a one-shot task.

Comment: Why use a `WHILE` loop at all? You would be far better off with an `IDENTITY` property or Tally, depending on your requirement.

Comment: This table will be used to interface with an embedded system. The intention is to have exactely 512 rows, no more or less. So this is no dynamic system where data is added or removed; only single values will be changed.

Comment: Also that code you gave us doesn't replicate the problem you say you have: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7d1279cff4dba7837868112db8214a56)

Comment: Still, a tally would be far better than a `WHILE`.

Comment: Create 512 rows using a tally: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b9b85bc7e92784ba0288f49907d33dc)

Comment: Thanks, I had to look up tally first.

Comment: Forget the loop entirely and use a tally table as suggested. Here is a great article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It's somewhat embarassing but obviously when creating the table I created it with type bit for the Id column instead of int.